# Trying to parse JSON to String in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse this stock info at:

http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=csco

that's in JSON format to a map, essentially following this tutorial I saw using the quick-json jar but it keeps giving me an exception and I can't figure out why. Here's the code, any help is greatly appreciated

Tutorial link: https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    String value="";
    URL uri = new URL("http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=csco");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uri.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while(input.readLine()!=null)
    {
        value+=input.readLine();
    }
    JsonParserFactory factory = JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
    JSONParser parse = factory.newJsonParser();
    Map jsonData =parse.parseJson(value);
    System.out.println((String)jsonData.get("e"));
}
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.json.exceptions.JSONParsingException: @Key-Heirarchy::root[0]/   @Key::  COMMA or ] is expected. but found :...@Position::5
    at com.json.utils.JSONUtility.handleFailure(JSONUtility.java:124)
    at com.json.parsers.JSONParser.stringLiteralTemplate(JSONParser.java:574)
    at com.json.parsers.JSONParser.nonValidatingValueTemplate(JSONParser.java:698)
    at com.json.parsers.JSONParser.jsonArrayTemplate(JSONParser.java:454)
    at com.json.parsers.JSONParser.parseJson(JSONParser.java:170)
    at parser.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:27)
```

EDIT: I also tried Map jsonData =parse.parseJson(value.substring(3) to start at [ but it still gives me an error

Comment: It tells you in exception that part of the input did not have the expected separator.

Comment: yeah but it it's in the  correct format from what i can tell so I don't know **why** it's telling it it's not

Comment: It looks like you are adding 1 line every 2 readLine() inside "value" during the while loop.

Comment: `// ` is not parsable here

Comment: Use one of the several "[Online JSON parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)" web pages you can find with Google to validate your JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to removing the leading `//` fix your loop as well. Change

```
while(input.readLine()!=null) // skipping odd lines
{
    value+=input.readLine(); // reading even lines
}
```

to

```
String line = null;
while((line = input.readLine()) !=null)
{
    value +=line;
}
```

or, better use a `StringBuilder` like

```
String line = null;
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
while((line = input.readLine()) !=null)
{
    json.append(line);
}
value = json.substring(3); // removes the leading "// "
```

***EDIT**:*
I'm not familiar with your JSON parser. With the [org.json.](http://www.json.org) Java parser you could do it this way.

```
JSONArray jsonRoot = new JSONArray(value);
JSONObject quote = jsonRoot.get(0);
System.out.println ("e = " + quote.getString("e"));
```

But, as a workaround you could strip the `[]` from `StringBuilder` as

```
// removes the leading "// [" and trailing "]"
value = json.substring(4, json.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Skipping lines from input is not a problem?

Comment: Sorry, I totally looked over that, thanks for pointing that out, can't believe I still make that mistake now and then. It works now but it returns null. So it's not parsing correctly, any suggestions

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: quick-json. According to the debugger it's putting everything in "root". Am I forgetting some fundamental rule of hash tables?

Comment: Yes, the problem is your Map {} is within a JSON array []. You may need to explore the API some more to get two levels down into your json.

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial just did it in that fashion so I figured it should be okay. I'll keep looking. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This json is not a valid, have two "//".

Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate this

Answer (score 1):

The response from that URL starts with `//`, which isn't valid JSON:

> // [ { "id": "99624" ,"t" : "CSCO" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "24.00" ,"l_cur" : "24.00" ,"s": "2" ,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT" ,"lt" : "Jun 25, 4:00PM EDT" ,"c" : "-0.05" ,"cp" : "-0.21" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"el": "24.00" ,"el_cur": "24.00" ,"elt" : "Jun 25, 5:54PM EDT" ,"ec" : "0.00" ,"ecp" : "0.00" ,"eccol" : "chb" ,"div" : "0.17" ,"yld" : "2.83" } ]

According to [this](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html) and [this](https://developers.google.com/finance/), the Google Finance API is deprecated anyway, so you may want to find something else.

Comment: right, I also tried it with value.substring(3) to start it at the "[" but it still gives me an error

Comment: same one: Exception in thread "main" com.json.exceptions.JSONParsingException: "@"Key-Heirarchy::root[0]/ "@"Key:: COMMA or ] is expected. but found :...@Position::6

Answer (score 1):

Following blog has enough number of very good examples on quick-json parser

It has got other competitive parsers examples as well

http://codesnippets4all.com/html/parsers/json/quick-json.htm

Comment: Nice source . Try adding the relevant example in your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
    String line = null;
    while((line = input.readLine()) !=null)
    {
        value += line;
    }
    value = value.replace("// ", "");
```

You need to replace the `//` at the beginning to "clean" the JSON before you can parse it.

Comment: @brendan long if you check the input the only occurence is at the beginning and I'm fairly positive it won't happen again.

Comment: If you look at once particular case of the input, then it *seems* to be safe, but it's still overkill, and unnecessarily increases the risk of bugs. It would be safer *and* more efficient to do: `if(value.startswith("//")) value = value.substr(2);`.

Comment: @brendan long yea I do agree with you. Just coded this for a specific question. I would edit it but I'm on the mobile device at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are using old quick-json parser version. Use the latest version for parsing

quick-json-1.0.2.3.jar

I could see that the json is coming as follows,

```
// [
{
"id": "99624"
,"t" : "CSCO"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "25.41"
,"l_cur" : "25.41"
,"s": "2"
,"ltt":"3:59PM EDT"
,"lt" : "Jul 10, 3:59PM EDT"
,"c" : "+0.25"
,"cp" : "1.01"
,"ccol" : "chg"
,"el": "25.55"
,"el_cur": "25.55"
,"elt" : "Jul 10, 7:07PM EDT"
,"ec" : "+0.14"
,"ecp" : "0.55"
,"eccol" : "chg"
,"div" : "0.17"
,"yld" : "2.68"
}
]
```

This is not valid JSON,  it should not be preceded by `//`

```
// [
```

remove `//` and just use from `[` till end of the json string

i was able to parse successfully the below json string without `//`

```
[
{
"id": "99624"
,"t" : "CSCO"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "25.41"
,"l_cur" : "25.41"
,"s": "2"
,"ltt":"3:59PM EDT"
,"lt" : "Jul 10, 3:59PM EDT"
,"c" : "+0.25"
,"cp" : "1.01"
,"ccol" : "chg"
,"el": "25.55"
,"el_cur": "25.55"
,"elt" : "Jul 10, 7:07PM EDT"
,"ec" : "+0.14"
,"ecp" : "0.55"
,"eccol" : "chg"
,"div" : "0.17"
,"yld" : "2.68"
}
]
```

Below is the output i've got with version **quick-json-1.0.2.3.jar**

```
{root=[{e=NASDAQ, c=+0.25, div=0.17, l=25.41, lt=Jul 10, 3:59PM EDT, ec=+0.14, ltt=3:59PM EDT, elt=Jul 10, 7:07PM EDT, id=99624, yld=2.68, el_cur=25.55, t=CSCO, cp=1.01, s=2, el=25.55, l_cur=25.41, eccol=chg, ccol=chg, ecp=0.55}]}
```